# 000Webhost mixed (PHP mysqli and PDO)

Tags: php, ionic-framework, mysqli, pdo, host

I'm trying to put my database online put in my code i have `PHP` files that are only `PHP` and others `PDO` .

I added 2 different connections to each :

database.php(PDO)

```
$user='';
$pass='';
$db='';
$dbserver='';


try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbserver;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully"; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {    
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

One of the  PDO files I started with :

```
<?php
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');

include('database.php');

  try {
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbserver;dbname=$db", $user, $pass);
// set the PDO error mode to exception
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
echo "Connected successfully"; 
} catch(PDOException $e) {    
echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

 $data = array();



     $a_username         = filter_var($_POST['a_username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
     $p_username         = filter_var($_POST['p_username'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
     $password           = filter_var($_POST['password'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);
     $vpassword          = filter_var($_POST['vpassword'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_ENCODE_LOW);

try{

        $sql  = "INSERT INTO account_info (a_username,p_username, password, vpassword) 
            VALUES(:a_username, :p_username, :password, :vpassword)";

        $stmt    = $conn->prepare($sql);    

        $stmt->bindParam(':a_username', $a_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':p_username', $p_username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindParam(':vpassword', $vpassword, PDO::PARAM_STR);

        $stmt->execute();

        echo json_encode(array('message' => 'Congratulations the record was added to the database'));

}
     catch(PDOException $e)
     {
        echo $e->getMessage();
     }      
 ?>
```

No more errors but I still can't log in from my phone

Comment: Do not mix mysql APIs. You'll just give yourself a headache. Why would you want to?

Comment: I originally had my code in` PDO` but i couldn't do some stuff with it and I found the solution with `mysqli` i know it's not the optimal solution but is there a way it might work ?

Comment: is there a way i can maybe link the `PDOs` together in  `database1` and the `mysqli`s in `database2` together and then link them  ?

Comment: Or maybe put both in one `database.php` and put an if statement ?

Comment: That can work. You won't be able to use them in the same call, but you can get the results from each one, and then manipulate them yourself.

Comment: I created 2 separate but this error occurs : `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in...` on :  `$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);`

Comment: Then your PDO connection failed. Check for PDO errors to see what the problem might be.

Comment: when I add `include('database.php');`  should I keep or remove `$dsn  = "mysql:host=" . $hn . ";port=3306;dbname=" . $db . ";charset=" . $cs;
$opt  = array(
                    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE            => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                    PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE => PDO::FETCH_OBJ,
                    PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES   => false,
                   );

 $pdo  = new PDO($dsn, $un, $pwd, $opt);`
 from my pdo files

Comment: It should all be in one place.

Comment: fixed I got no more errors but i still can't log in